# unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was trying to include datagrid view in my project and the error_({"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}) was shown.

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This is the code where error pops up:-
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=PatDatabaseDataSet;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Name"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        connection.Open(){underlined part was highlighted as the error location}
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Patient_table")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables()
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Patient_table"
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Make an exception in the code where the error has came , with Try-catch block

Here is the sample:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        connection()
        Sql = "Select * From LoginTable Where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' And password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "LoginTable")
        If ds.Tables("LoginTable").Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Me.Hide()
            Dim Menu As New Form
            Menu.Show()
        Else

            MsgBox("Login Failed")
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch
        MsgBox("Login Failed")
    End Try
End Sub
```